# Activesupport titlecase() with bang (.titlecase!)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

I currently have a string with customer names that I am titlecasing with:

```
@customer_name = @customer_name.titlecase
```

But this seems a bit long-winded. When I try to do:

```
@customer_name.titlecase!
```

I get a no method error. Does `titlecase!` exist? It seems odd that there wouldn't be a way to do this, since there is a `downcase!`, for example.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1253/rant-tag-should-it-exist

Comment: This is not a rant, it is a genuine question - I want to know if I can use the method with a bang, or if there is something I need to include first.

Answer (score 1):

You can see on http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M000381 that all titlecase does is this (also notice there are no bang methods)

```
def titleize
  Inflector.titleize(self)
end
```

So, if you wanted to implement this is

```
class String
  def titleize!
    replace titleize
  end
end
```

Then:

```
>> the_string = "oh hai"
=> "oh hai"
>> the_string.titleize!
=> "Oh Hai"
>> the_string
=> "Oh Hai"
```

Answer (score 0):

downcase with or without bang are Ruby methods. titlecase is not. Perhaps, that is the reason that it does not have the bang version. Rails developers probably did not bother to define the bang version.